# Android Google Map: Dynamic Map zoom Level vs Static Map Zoom Level

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.android, maps

I have to use Google dynamic map to search a location, scroll, zoom, etc and  then take a screenshot of the map. Due to license restriction, I cannot take a screenshot (GMap.Snapshot(this)). So it was decided to download an image from google static map

When the user wants to switch from map dynamic mode to static map, he clicks a button and I take center latitude and longitude, zoom level and map size (it's xamarin android)

```
        {
            CenterLatLng = new double[] { GMap.CameraPosition.Target.Latitude, GMap.CameraPosition.Target.Longitude },
            ZoomLevel = (int)GMap.CameraPosition.Zoom,
            Type = GMap.MapType,
            MapSize = new int[] { MapFragment.View.MeasuredWidth, MapFragment.View.MeasuredHeight }
        };
```

with this parameters i will try to download a static map

```
        int scale = 2;
        var url = $"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center={myobject.CenterLatLng[0]},{myobject.CenterLatLng[1]}&zoom={myobject.ZoomLevel}&size={myobject.MapSize[0] / scale}x{myobject.MapSize[1] / scale}&scale={scale}&maptype=satellite&format=png&key=xxxxxxxx";
```

but downloaded static map seems to have a different zoom from dynamic Map

[Here a screenshot of the Dynamic Map displayed before than switching to Static map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVWDm.jpg)

[Here a screenshot of the Static Map displayed after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHLZ2.jpg)

how can I fix that difference between dynamic map zoom and static map zoom?

Answer (score 0):

> how can I fix that difference between dynamic map zoom and static map zoom?

I think the issue is caused by the size you set in the url `size={myobject.MapSize[0] / scale}x{myobject.MapSize[1] / scale}`.
You could create a new variable to divide the `MapSize` instead of using `scale` to change the size.

Comment: how much i have do divide MapSize? I found out a solution scaling to 512            
            sketchbkgmap.MapSize = new int[] { width, height };
            var mapBmpScale = Math.Min(512f / width, 512f / height);
              var url = $"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?........&size={(int)(width * mapBmpScale)}x{(int)(height * mapBmpScale)}.......

Comment: It is working quite well but in rare cases static map is different from what i can see with dynamic map